# How to handle json api arrays in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, newsapi

I am getting data from newsapi for my flutter app. How to get the id of the source in this json data?

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 38, 

"articles": [
 {   
"source": {
"id": "independent",
"name": "Independent"
},
"author": "Rachel Sharp",
"title": "Idaho murders - updates: Moscow police spark confusion over ‘targeted’ attack as crime scene results come back - The Independent",
"description": "Update on Idaho student murders",
"url": example.com,
"urlToImage": example.com,
"publishedAt": "2022-12-01T09:53:10Z",
"content": "ICYMI: Neighbour of victims hits out at Reddit sleuths\r\nA neighbour of the four University of Idaho students who were murdered on 13 November has hit out at Reddit sleuths who claimed that his media"
},
}
```

ArticleModel.dart

```
class ArticleModel {
  String? author;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? url;
  String? urlToImage;
  String? content;
  String? publishedAt;

  ArticleModel({required this.author, required this.title, required this.description, required this.url, required this.urlToImage, required this.content, required this.publishedAt});
}
```

SourceModel.dart

```
class SourceModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  String description;
  String url;
  String category;
  String country;
  String language;

  SourceModel({required this.id, required this.name, required this.description, required this.url, required this.category,
      required this.country, required this.language});
}
```

This method returns the list of available sources

```
class SourceListClass {
  List<SourceModel> source = [];

  Future<void> getSourceList() async {
    String url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines/sources?country=us&apiKey=45dd80f272ae40d5af76a796acee8529";

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (jsonData['status'] == 'ok') {
      jsonData['sources'].forEach((element) {

        if (element['name'] != null) {

          SourceModel sourceModel = SourceModel(
            id: element['id'],
            name: element['name'],
            description: element['description'],
            url: element['url'],
            category: element['category'],
            country: element['country'],
            language: element['language'],
          );

          source.add(sourceModel);
        }
      });
    }
    print("");
  }
}
```

With this method I am getting other data except source without issues.

Articles.dart

```
class News {
  List<ArticleModel> news = [];

  Future<void> getNews() async {
    String url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=45dd80f272ae40d5af76a796acee8529";

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (jsonData['status'] == 'ok') {
      jsonData['articles'].forEach((element) {

        if (element['urlToImage'] != null && element['description'] != null) {

          ArticleModel articleModel = ArticleModel(
            title: element['title'],
            author: element['author'],
            description: element['description'],
            url: element['url'],
            urlToImage: element['urlToImage'],
            content: element['context'],
            publishedAt: element['publishedAt'],
          );
          news.add(articleModel);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add id of the source to this method

Comment: you can add a SourceModel class instance in ArticleModel perform toJson and fromJson method for it and then you can access the SourceModels all variable through articleModel instance like `ArticleModel article;`   `article.source.id`

Comment: Can you help me with code for this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can access the id of the source with:

```
var id = element['source']['id'];
```

Full example:

```
class News {
  List<ArticleModel> news = [];

  Future<void> getNews() async {
    String url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=45dd80f272ae40d5af76a796acee8529";

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (jsonData['status'] == 'ok') {
      jsonData['articles'].forEach((element) {

        if (element['urlToImage'] != null && element['description'] != null) {
          
          // get id of source
          var id = element['source']['id'];

          ArticleModel articleModel = ArticleModel(
            title: element['title'],
            author: element['author'],
            description: element['description'],
            url: element['url'],
            urlToImage: element['urlToImage'],
            content: element['context'],
            publishedAt: element['publishedAt'],
          );
          news.add(articleModel);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps! :)